# Set Condition for Httppost in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one anchor link called "edit". Once i click "edit" button that name will changes to "Save". I need to do http post operation on when link names changes to "Save". I don't know how to perform that only for "save" process.

[image: Image is given below]

Comment: you mean ASP.NET MVC? please correct your title

Comment: you can add the attribute to your Grid Link button `type="submit"`

Comment: @Ravi - I don't think that would work since you'd need a form wrapped around each row, and that's just not valid HTML.

Comment: Can you use JavaScript or jQuery? You can then ajax your data via .post

Comment: are you using client side approach to update the date ?

Comment: I agree with freshbm, use Ajax for something like this.

Comment: yes im using client side appraoch @Ravi

Comment: then you can easily use the HTTP abbreviation "POST" "GET" etc while making a request using jQuery